# Are Harmonic or Subharmonic resonance the only outcomes for a system with applied vibrations?

Tags: vibrations

I'm working on performing a linear stability analysis on a system with fluid undergoing applied vibrations. Now, usually these systems are analyzed with no fluid velocity. Under these conditions, it can be shown that the system reduces to the form of a Mathieu equation (or a modified Mathieu equation in the case of viscous fluid). For Mathieu equations, it's known that there are discrete regions where the system response is either Harmonic or Subharmonic resonance, which is in line with the Faraday instability that's observed on the fluid interface. However, what happens when the system equations cannot be reduced to the form of Mathieu equations (for example, for complex fluids or fluids with flow)? Can the system allow resonance at frequencies outside of Harmonic and Subharmonic, or is there something more fundamental that says that these are the only allowable options? Should I also consider the possibility that the response might not even be periodic?

[Analysis procedure for inviscid Newtonian fluids](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1954.0218)
[Analysis procedure for viscous Newtonian fluids](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112094003812)